# Does the EntityDataSource support "it.Property.Property" syntax?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I have an EntityDataSource where I'm trying to replace some previous code-behind work. My EntityDataSource looks like:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource 
        runat="server" 
        ID="personDataSource" 
        ContextTypeName="Model.GuidesEntities" 
        EntitySetName="CharacterFavorites" 
        OrderBy="it.Person.FullName" 
        Select="it.Person.Id" 
        Where="it.UserName = @userName" />
```

When when I actually use it I get the error:

> 'Person' is not a member of type
>   'Transient.rowtype[(Id,Edm.Int32(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=))]' in
>   the currently loaded schemas.

Does the EntityDataSource not support walking the relationships? How would you do this with the EntityDataSource?

Also the `@userName` parameter is being added in the code behind for now. Extra points for anyone who knows how to specify a username parameter directly in the WhereParameters collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard predefined parameter type which allows you to get the current user name as a Where parameter in markup (I guess you are talking about `User.Identity.Name`). Something simple like...

```
<asp:Parameter Name="userName" DefaultValue='<%# User.Identity.Name %>' />
```

...doesn't work unfortunately since you cannot use data binding syntax in the parameter controls.

But you can create [custom parameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150717/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110106-1.aspx). (On the second half of that page is a concrete example of a "user name parameter".)

To your problem with the exception: I'm using the "it-Syntax" with navigation properties a lot in EntityDataSource and it looks more or less exactly like your example. Without seeing more of your model it's hard to tell what might cause the error. But generally, navigating through properties in EntityDataSource is supported and works.

Answer (score 2):

EF uses "super lazy loading" here (my own term). It doesn't automatically reach out and grab the associated "Person" object. You MUST specify inside the entotyDataSource what other objects to make available. So you need to add this line: "Include="Person". See below:

```
 <asp:EntityDataSource 
        runat="server" 
        ID="personDataSource" 
        ContextTypeName="Model.GuidesEntities" 
        EntitySetName="CharacterFavorites" 
        OrderBy="it.Person.FullName" 
        Select="it.Person.Id" 
        Where="it.UserName = @userName" 
        Include="Person"  />
```

If you need to add multiple associations, separate them with commas: Include="Person, Dog, Chicken, SalesOrder" 
Also, it's "==" not "=" in your Where clause.

Comment: It was just pointed out to me that if you also include the "Dog" object in your Include property, and also want to get to it's "Collar" nav property, then you add "Dog.Collar" to the Include as well. "Collar" by itself will break.

Comment: This is the correct answer (it.NavigationProperty.Field). One thing. When you go to use it in a databinding expression later, use only the field name, not NavigationProperty.Field to databind. That tripped me up.

Comment: I suppose I should clarify because otherwise it'll seem to contradict what Graham said in his comment.  If we're going off of Graham's Select above, it.Person.Id should be Eval'ed as Eval("Id").

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void MyNotesSelecting(object sender, EntityDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
            {
                e.DataSource.Where = "it.UserName=="+User.Identity.Name
            }
```